# Running a linux command from Django views. Works fine in python shell. Won't execute from views

Tags: python, django, apache

I have tried using both subprocess() and os.system()

```
import os
def whatever(request):
    open file
    code write to file
    close file
    os.system(command theFileIwroteto argument)
```

Now the code is fine. I have opened python and literally copied and pasted the exact command in and it works fine.

python:

```
import os
os.system(command theFileIwroteto argument)
```

Why would it work using the python shell but refuse to execute from the django views file?

Comment: How are you running the view?  You tagged it apache, which would make me think you're running this as wsgi (as opposed to the django dev server etc.)  What OS are you running?

Comment: Do you get `IOError: sys.stdout access restricted by mod_wsgi`?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the error log in order to make a proper diagnostic.

Without more information, I can think of two reasons:

1. The Apache mod_wsgi restricts access to stdout, and the command you are running outputs to stdout. If you are using mod_wsgi, look for errors like `IOError: sys.stdout access restricted by mod_wsgi` in the logs;
2. You are testing your command while logged in as your user or root, but the webserver is running as other user with less privileges (like www-data in Ubuntu). Find out under what user the webserver is running, `su` to the same user and try the same commands. Any error will hint you about the permissions lacking.

It is almost always a bad idea to run a shell from a Django view, specially if the command take a few seconds to run. It has bad scalability, makes easier for someone to DDoS your site and makes responses slow. The proper way to do it is to place the job on a queue and have one or more background processes consuming this queue. Take a look at [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html), its  popular for this kind of task.